# maintain dictionary structure while reducing nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, nested-lists

I have a list of pairs of nested dict `dd` and would like to maintain the structure to a list of dictionaries:

```
dd = [
    [{'id': 'bla',
      'detail': [{'name': 'discard', 'amount': '123'},
                 {'name': 'KEEP_PAIR_1A', 'amount': '2'}]},
     {'id': 'bla2',
      'detail': [{'name': 'discard', 'amount': '123'},
                 {'name': 'KEEP_PAIR_1B', 'amount': '1'}]}
    ],
    [{'id': 'bla3',
      'detail': [{'name': 'discard', 'amount': '123'},
                 {'name': 'KEEP_PAIR_2A', 'amount': '3'}]},
     {'id': 'bla4',
      'detail': [{'name': 'discard', 'amount': '123'},
                 {'name': 'KEEP_PAIR_2B', 'amount': '4'}]}
    ]
]
```

I want to reduce this to a list of paired dictionaries while extracting only some detail. For example, an expected output may look like this:

```
[{'name': ['KEEP_PAIR_1A', 'KEEP_PAIR_1B'], 'amount': [2, 1]},
 {'name': ['KEEP_PAIR_2A', 'KEEP_PAIR_2B'], 'amount': [3, 4]}]
```

I have run my code:

```
pair=[]
for all_pairs in dd:
    for output_pairs in all_pairs:
        for d in output_pairs.get('detail'):
            if d['name'] != 'discard':
                pair.append(d)
output_pair = {
    k: [d.get(k) for d in pair]
    for k in set().union(*pair)
}
```

But it didn't maintain that structure :

```
{'name': ['KEEP_PAIR_1A', 'KEEP_PAIR_1B', 'KEEP_PAIR_2A', 'KEEP_PAIR_2B'],
 'amount': ['2', '1', '3', '4']}
```

I assume I would need to use some list comprehension to solve this but where in the for loop should I do that to maintain the structure.

Comment: if items are pairs, you don't need the inner loop

Comment: does the detail always contain a single item which is important?

Comment: It may not be, but more likely the discarded detail is always single. The answer by @enke works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to combine dictionaries in lists, one option is to use `dict.setdefault`:

```
pair = []
for all_pairs in dd:
    dct = {}
    for output_pairs in all_pairs:
        for d in output_pairs.get('detail'):
            if d['name'] != 'discard':
                for k,v in d.items():
                    dct.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
    pair.append(dct)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': ['KEEP_PAIR_1A', 'KEEP_PAIR_1B'], 'amount': [2, 1]},
 {'name': ['KEEP_PAIR_2A', 'KEEP_PAIR_2B'], 'amount': [3, 4]}]
```